# How to add a sub-app in django to INSTALLED_APPS?

Tags: django

I have the structure of my project:

```
project
———— project
———— app
———————— subapp
    ———— manage.py
```

I added my sub-app to INSTALLED_APPS like that:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = ['app.apps.AppConfig', 'app.subapp.apps.SubapConfig']
```

But it doesn't works. Django gives me an error message:

> No module named 'news' and Cannot import 'news'. Check that
>   'apps.subapp.apps.SubapConfig.name' is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume I've created an app named `polls` with the following command:

```
python manage.py startapp polls
```

Now I want to create a sub-app named `subpoll` inside the main app means inside the `polls` folder. So, how do I do that?

1. At first, I'll create a directory `My_App_Name` inside the `/polls` folder. In my case, I'll create a `subpoll` folder inside the `polls` folder.
2. After that, run the following command to create the new app.

```
python manage.py startapp My_App_Name ./polls/Your_Apps_Folder_Name/
```

So, in my case the following command will be like:

```
python manage.py startapp subpoll ./polls/subpoll/
```

Finally, I'll add just created apps name in the `settings.py` like below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    'polls',
    'polls.subpoll',

]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In the `apps.py` `Config` class you need to set name to be the full dotted path. So based on the structure you give:

```
project
———— project
———— app
———————— subapp
    ———— manage.py
```

You would have:

```
class AppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "app"
```

and

```
class SubappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "app.subapp"
```

This should then work for you.